# schema.org BusinessFunction - GoodRelations

Tags: schema.org

I want to mark web page with schema.org tags. I can find in the documentation that one can specify a kind o business with using tag: BusinessFunction and tag from GoodRelations.
The problem is I can not find example of it. Because the web page is about software developer I'm going to use  tag: http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#ProvideService.

Can anybody give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: A related yet bit outdated resource on modeling services with GoodRelations (and thus schema.org) is here: http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/GoodRelationsService

This explains the basic pattern. Note that Some GoodRelations elements have slightly different names in schema.org, as listed here: http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Cookbook/Schema.org#Naming_Differences

I plan to update this page and migrate it to [the new GoodRelations Cookbook](http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Cookbook). But this is an open issue and will take me a while.

Now, for your concrete question: The use of

```
http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#ProvideService
```

is fine if the good you offer is providing a certain service.

Here is a full example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemid="#offer">
  <div itemprop="name">Web Development Services</div>
  <div itemprop="description">We build your Web site....</div>
  <link itemprop="businessFunction"
        href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#ProvideService" />
<!-- Unit price -->
  <div itemscope itemprop="priceSpecification"
       itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">Price:
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$
    <span itemprop="price">50.00</span> per
    <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="HUR"> hour
    <time itemprop="validThrough"
          datetime="2013-11-30T23:59:59Z"></time>
  </div>
<!-- other offer properties follow here -->
...
</div>
```