# Would it be Appropriate to use the Product Schema for Services?

Tags: schema.org

I am interested in tagging the page that features all the services.

My particular industry Schema doesn't offer the span `itemprop="itemOffered"`. Thus, should I make each the services page reflect the Product Schema rather than the industry specific itemtype, Or is it best to specify on the services page the product Schema and then on the individual product pages use the industry-specific itemtype and list the product using `makesoffer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, Poe, a product can also be a service.  So in your case (without knowing more info about what you offer), you can use the Product Schema for your service.

However, there is another way to mark up your service, which is by using a GoodRelations markup to augment the Schema.org/Offer markup.  Here's a link to another stackoverflow post that perhaps can give a better example that I can:  [Using Schema.org and GoodRelations markups for services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121886/schema-org-businessfunction-goodrelations)

Hope that helps.