# HTML5 tags and microdata for a list of apartments

Tags: html, semantic-markup, microdata

which HTML5 tags and microdata schema should I use to describe a list of apartments to rent?

They have the following properties:

- Name
- Image
- Unique number
- Location
- Description
- Price

My HTML structure is currently like this:

```
<section id="featured">
    <h2>Featured appartaments</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <article>
                <h3><a href="javascript:void(0);">House #1</a></h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/" alt="House #1" />
                <p>Ref. 40</p>
                <p>My location</p>
                <p>My description.</p>
                <p>Price: € 500.000,00</p>
            </article>
        </li>
        <li>
            <article>
                <h3><a href="javascript:void(0);">House #2</a></h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/" alt="House #2" />
                <p>Ref. 41</p>
                <p>My location</p>
                <p>My description.</p>
                <p>Price: € 500.000,00</p>
            </article>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you checked schema.org already? For a start maybe look at http://schema.org/Residence

Comment: Yes I did, but this is the first time for me using microdata and it seems that I'd need a mix of Product and Residence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update (2016):** Schema.org now has new types/properties for accommodations, including an `Apartment` type. See the [update in my related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25161374/1591669). I’ll leave the old answer below unchanged for now.

---

If you want to use the [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) vocabulary:

Each apartment could be represented by a [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) (bold emphasis mine):

> Any **offered product or service**. For example: a pair of shoes; a concert ticket; **the rental of a car**; a haircut; or an episode of a TV show streamed online.

The offer to rent such an apartment could be represented by an [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer):

> An **offer to transfer some rights to an item or to provide a service**—for example, an offer to sell tickets to an event, **to rent the DVD of a movie**, to stream a TV show over the internet, to repair a motorcycle, or to loan a book.

For linking from the `Product` to the `Offer`, use the [`offers` property](http://schema.org/offers) (resp. the [`itemOffered` property](http://schema.org/itemOffered) for the other direction).

It’s also possible to use `Offer` on its own (without using `Product` at all), and judging from your example, this might make sense here.  (Using `Offer` *and* `Product` makes sense when you have different offers for the same apartment, i.e., you can give the metadata for the apartment in the `Product` and use separate `Offer` items for different dates etc.).

So using your example, it could look like:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <h3 itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="">House #1</a></h3>
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://placehold.it/250x150/" alt="House #1" />
  <p itemprop="serialNumber">Ref. 40</p>
  <p>My location</p>
  <p itemprop="description">My description.</p>
  <p>Price: € <span itemprop="price">500.000,00</span> <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" /></p>
</article>
```

There is no property for specifying the address of the offered apartment. `Offer` only allows for giving the address/place where you can *obtain* the offer ([`availableAtOrFrom`](http://schema.org/availableAtOrFrom)). You could just use the [`PostalAddress`](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) type, but as there is no appropriate property to link it to `Offer`, there would be no machine-readable connection between the offer and the address.

Additionally, you might want to use

- [`businessFunction`](http://schema.org/businessFunction) → [BusinessFunction](http://schema.org/BusinessFunction) for specifying that it’s about *renting*,
- [`category`](http://schema.org/category) for specifying that it’s about an apartment (i.e., [`Residence`](http://schema.org/Residence)),
- etc.

Comment: Very clear and thorough answer, thanks! About the tags I used, are they correct?

Comment: @StockBreak: Yes, your use of HTML5 seems to be appropriate: the outline is correct, no misuse of elements. (Note that the chosen HTML5 elements, [with a few exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669), don’t matter for Microdata consumers; but there are of course plenty other reasons why correct/semantic markup is important.)

Comment: I searched around for a while but I couldn't find a concrete example about using businessFunction. Do I really have to use `<link />` elements? Would you please provice one to me? I have 2 types: Renting and Selling. I really appreciate your help unor!

Comment: @StockBreak: You could also use an `a` element, but it probably doesn’t make sense to have this as a visible link, so `link` is typically used (as it is hidden by default). See [Martin Hepp’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19128636/1591669) to a question about `BusinessFunction`.

Comment: suppose that I would like to add a <p> element under <p>My location</p> with the function (e.g. <p>For rent</p> or <p>Sell</p>), how would I describe it? You can also edit your answer and add it if you want. Thanks!

Comment: @StockBreak: Just add a `link` element somewhere in the `itemscope`, e.g.: `<p>For rent <link itemprop="businessFunction" href="…" /></p>`