# Semantic markup for an apartment site

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

We are about to launch a website where users can search for rental apartments. To please the Google search engine I want to mark all of my apartment related HTML elements with some semantic markup.

I have been looking at Schema.org and FOAF to find some good vocabs to use. But I can't seem to find vocabs that support apartment informations.

Example:

> 2 bedroom
>   300 square feet
>   Parkingspot

And so on. Right now I use `typeof="ApartmentComplex"` - but I want to markup the above.

Can anyone give me a hint on how I would mark up such information in a way that enables Google to display them as Rich Snippets and increase pageranking?

Comment: Looking for a Google Richsnippet for appartment? Sorry but currently, Google generates Rich Snippets only for: `Reviews`, `People`, `Products`, `Businesses and organizations`, `Recipes`, `Events`, `Music` (see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en)

Comment: In case you missed it, Schema.org now has more specific types/properties for your case (I updated my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Schema.org’s [`ApartmentComplex`](http://schema.org/ApartmentComplex) doesn’t seem to be appropriate if you want to markup a single apartment. So the parent type [`Residence`](http://schema.org/Residence) should be used instead. However, these `Place` types don’t have properties for marking up the things you are looking for.

[`Product`](http://schema.org/Product)/[`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) could also be used, but they also don’t have apartment-specific properties, of course (see my [answer about using `Offer` for renting apartments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24708098/1591669)).

So, as you seem to be interested only in Google and their Rich Snippets (and apart from some Microformats and deprecated data-vocabulary.org support, you’d have to use Schema.org), the answer is: **Currently not possible.**

---

#### Update 2016

In the last Schema.org version, v3.1, [types and properties for "hotels and other forms of accommodations"](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html) were introduced.

Now you can use the [`Apartment`](http://schema.org/Apartment) type, and provide your data with the [`numberOfRooms`](http://schema.org/numberOfRooms), [`floorSize`](http://schema.org/floorSize), and [`amenityFeature`](http://schema.org/amenityFeature) properties.

But Google Search still doesn’t seem to offer any related search result features.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I am not surprised of course. You are the markup guru! I am looking around for updated and fairly complete examples of marking up 1) an apartment for rent, 2) Apartment Complex, and possibly anything else that applies. I am starting here, however, if you know of some examples I can use as a template, that would be fantastic! Especially for apartment details. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc: Thanks for your comment; I made short update to my answer, as things have evolved in the meantime :) -- The current Schema.org version got a big update with types/properties relevant for various forms of accommodation. They have a documentation page that introduces/explains them: [Markup for Hotels](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html) (it’s not for hotels only). -- I don’t know any other resources, as I’ve not yet worked in this domain.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I did find some Json sample code that I quickly modified. It may not be complete, but it is a start. It is a shame that G does not recognize it yet. Still, it is something. I am using openElements to bang up a quick sample web site. Makes for messy code since everything is in a ugly div tag. Will make it mobile, deploy it to a dev web server, then clean it up later. Sucks. But it is making a sharp looking site none-the-less which is more than I can do. I suck at pretty. Good with code, but lack the imagination to be a web designer. We all have out limits. ;-) Cheers!!